# How make an input in two part. One not editable and the other like a standard input

Tags: html, kendo-ui

I would like to display in a textbox both ways. 
The first displays a value that cannot be erased(readonly). 
And the other that will behave as an input standard.

The input is in a kendo grid, I can use only one input.

**Can there be a solution on the side of masked textboxes? regex?**

Please help !

Comment: Cant you use two textboxes.One is readonly and another editable one

Comment: I can not use two textbox because it is in an input into a kendo ui grid

Comment: Do upvote my answer :)if it works

Comment: I don't have any reputations :(

Comment: thats ok man!!!.you will earn soon

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See if this solution works and solves your problem

html

```
<div id = "textbox" contenteditable></div>
```

css

```
    * {
    padding:none;
    margin:none;
    box-shadow:none;
    text-shadow:none;
}
div{
    outline:none;
}
#textbox{
    width:100px;
    height:20px;
    background:lightblue;
    border-left:none;
    position:relative;
    -webkit-transform:translate(100%);
}

#textbox:before{
    content:"Not Editable";
    width:100px;
    height:20px;
    background:lightblue;
    border-right:none;
    position:absolute;
    left:-100px;

}
```

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/sunil_hari/LxJ8v/1/)

Hope this helps.Instead of using a `input` box i have used a `contenteditable` `div`.

Answer (score 0):

please use readonly attribute  in textbox as below :)
Email: input type="text" name="email"
Country: input type="text" name="country" value="Norway" readonly

please use angular brakets

Comment: thank you for your reply, but I just want a readonly on the FIRST part of the same input.

Answer (score 0):

2 alternative;

First;
Use two textboxes side to side, one readonly other normal.

Second;
Add keylisteners to field and concat with your first readOnly part and user entry. and then set it to textfield. (dirty workaround :) )